# How to design difference size Grids in GridView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, gridview

[image]

I need to design like this Grid View using Flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view):

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
  crossAxisCount: 4,
  itemCount: 8,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => new Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          child: new Text('$index'),
        ),
      )),
  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
      new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1),
  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but i needs to design it with difference width and heights. like that photo.

Comment: your welcome, i've tried such layout, i think it's not a problem~